# How to handle rolls for in-game DND game

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, metagaming

My group is playing a scenario set in the modern everyday world (late 20th century) and we have got into a position where the characters must play a DND game. The outcome of this game is important because of a bet that will determine which player receives a certain wagered item.

How do I deal with this in terms of rolls? I'm thinking one roll for the in-game DND roll and then another for chance of success. Has anyone done this before? Is there a less tedious approach than double-rolling?

Comment: I'm not sure it'll change the answer, but you should probably scope this down to the specific edition you are playing. The different editions have some differences in rules which may well be applicable (fairly few "how to deal with rolls" rules are the exact same across editions)

Comment: What RPG system are you actually using outside the D&D recursion? It's not really clear what you mean by a second roll for "chance of success", if the outcome is meant to be based on what's happening in the recursive game.

Comment: Related: [Role-playing within role-playing \[closed\]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5738/52137), and I guess [this too](https://xkcd.com/244/).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? Is "who gets the wagered item" the only important outcome?

Comment: Why do you need "double-rolling"? What problem do you solve with the first roll?